# Forcing PyTorch to use CUDA globally

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I installed PyTorch with CUDA, but am unable to use my GPU with torch. Instead, it defaults to using my CPU.

`nvcc --version` returns `V11.6.124`. `nvidia-smi` returns my GPU. `torch.__version__` returns 1.12.0 in python. `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True` and `torch.cuda.current_device()` returns `0`.

I have tried defining a device such as, `device = torch.device("cuda:0") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")` and then moving to CUDA like: `torch.rand(10).to(device)`. I have also tried the potential global solution: `torch.cuda.set_device(device)`. Even so, torch is not using my GPU.

However, instead of pointing each tensor to `device` through `.to(device)`, I am searching for ways to force torch to always use CUDA globally.

Are there any ideas for how to globally force torch to use CUDA? Perhaps I am not implementing `.to(device)` correctly? Thank you--any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you reason that torch is using only the CPU? Does `torch.cuda.is_available` return `True`? Also worth checking if `torch.cuda.device_count()` is greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When monitoring my GPU, it is not being utilized. I do see a python process running when I check `nvidia-smi`. However, it's not using any memory and seems like a null process.